# True/False value giving output 1 or blank using PHP

Tags: php

I am facing one issue. I am setting boolean `true/false` value but when I am echo that value its showing me `1/blank` using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
  $qry="SELECT c.member_id,c.rest_name,c.quadrant,c.proviance,c.postal,c.address,c.country,c.city,c.person,c.mobile,c.url,c.share_url,c.premium,c.image,c.multiple_image,c.business_phone_no,c.latitude,c.longitude,q.quadrant AS quadrant_name,ct.city_name FROM db_restaurant_basic AS c LEFT JOIN db_quadrant AS q ON c.quadrant=q.quad_id LEFT JOIN db_city AS ct ON c.city=ct.city_id  WHERE c.member_id='".$member_id."' and c.status=1 ORDER BY rand()";
    $fetchqry=mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($fetchqry) > 0){
      while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchqry)){
          if($row1['multiple_image']==''){
              $available_image=false;
          }else{
             $available_image=true;
         }
      }
    }
echo  $available_image.'<br>';
```

Here that echo output is given me `1/blank value` . Here I need to get the `true/false` as output.

Comment: In your code php is reading **true** and **false** as boolean number so it is displaying as 1/blank. so make it string by putting inside the quotation mark as **"true"** and **"false"**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't support printing True/False, so you can use following as a work-around:

```
echo $available_image ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Or even simpler, you can use:

```
echo json_encode($available_image);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple explanation.

As the documentation page of [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) describes it, `echo` outputs one or more [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).
Since the value of `$available_image` is not a string but a [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), conversion is required.

The [documentation page of strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), section [Converting to string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) explains:

> A boolean `TRUE` value is converted to the string `"1"`. Boolean `FALSE` is converted to `""` (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.

This is how PHP works. Also take a look at the [type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

If you need to display `true` or `false` (as strings), all you have to do is to use `$available_image` as the condition into a [ternary comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to produce the strings you need:

```
echo $available_image ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Or, if you print the value of `$available_image` only for debug purposes, you can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead of `echo()`. It displays not only the value (of the expression passed to it) as string (it produces `true` and `false` for booleans) but also the type of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual for [casting to string](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting). Try this:

```
echo $available_image ? 'true' : 'false', '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare the $available_image at the top of your code and set default value TRUE/FASLE to it like follows

```
  $available_image = FALSE;
```